# Index out of bounds inside a for loop

Tags: matlab

I am trying to loop till the length of Ytotal. But inside the loop some of the elements of Ytotal are getting deleted as the conditions are met. So , the length of Ytotal should be adjusted accordingly. But, still i am getting the error "index out of bounds" . Could anyone suggest me where i am wrong. thanks

```
    for aa = 1:length(Ytotal)
            if Ytotal(aa) > ymean+yerrorstd;
                Ytotal(aa)=[];
                x(aa)=[];
            else
                Ytotal(aa)=Ytotal(aa); 
                x(aa)=x(aa);
            end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ytotal(aa)=[];
```

deletes values in the array. do you really want to do that? wouldn't it be better to set them to zero?

```
Ytotal(aa) = 0;
```

if you delete an entire value the array shrinks. but you've set the range for aa already. if some values got deleted and aa reaches its top it will exceed the array.

and what should the code in the else path do? if you assign ytotal to itself. you could skip that.

Comment: thanks a lot sir.. i rectified my error as gryphon pointed out. I needed that else statement to make sure that the elements in the array gets assigned to its new indices after deletion of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If the loop is that simple, you just don't need it. Here's the equivalent

```
idx = Ytotal <= ymean+yerrorstd;
Ytotal = Ytotal(idx);
X = X(idx);
```

Using for-loop with deletion is a really bad approach. Create an index of elements to delete, copy result to a new array, or use while with counter instead (still a bad approach, but sometimes intuitive)

```
num_total = length(Ytotal);
num_ready = 0;
num_position = 1;
while num_ready < num_total
    if Ytotal(num_position) > ymean+yerrorstd;
        Ytotal(num_position)=[];
        x(num_position)=[];
    else
        Ytotal(num_position)=Ytotal(num_position); 
        x(num_position)=x(num_position);
        num_position = num_position +1;
    end
    num_ready = num_ready+1;
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. i will definitely keep it in mind next time .